# Does SSL cause Facebook iframe width to be only 480 px?

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

UPDATE: I just learned that the iframe width is 480 px only when viewed over a secure connection, possibly because I am using social-server.com rather than having my own ssl.

I've designed a page tab to be displayed in a Facebook iframe. I designed it with 520 px in mind as the maximum width. However, Facbook loads the page in an iframe that is only 480 pixels wide.

It looks like it is supposed to be 520 pixels wide, because there is extra white space between the iframe and the next column. Also, I checked other pages with other custom tabs, and their iframe is 520 pixels wide.

So I wonder if this is a new limit on new custom tabs. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom tab width is 520px, perhaps you need to set body margins to 0px in your css. Check this out.

Comment: The body margins and padding already are set to 0. But when I load the page in Facebook, the actual page source shows iframe width="480" not 520.

Comment: UPDATE: I just learned that the iframe width is 480 px only when viewed over a secure connection, possibly because I am using social-server.com rather than having my own ssl.

Comment: I have it 520px on both SSL and not SSL, it might be related to the site you mentioned.

Comment: These CSS settings are correct. But it turns out that yes, social-server.com (basically a URL shortener that provides a secure connection) has a setting to set width, which I had not seen.

Answer (score 0):

i was struggling with this too - 480px wide is not actually a restriction, but it is the width your page will become if a vertical scroll bar get inserted - which happens if you don't specify the length of your page on the social server interface. you can change the dimensions, and hit the yellow refresh arrows, then refresh in facebook and it should look how you intend.